# Settings up postcss to use VH fix

Tags: javascript, css

I'm attempting to use PostCSS to fix the problem where 100vh doesn't account for the browser/navigation bar on mobile devices.

https://github.com/Faisal-Manzer/postcss-viewport-height-correction

The problem is, I have no idea how to set it up and the instructions assume I know how. I have very little experience with JavaScript and don't use any frameworks or know how to, I just do everything in VS Code with no plugins.

I installed the PostCSS extension in VS Code but am unsure what to do next.

The installation says:

"And then add this javascript to public/index.html (for React), or add to template.html (for Preact)."

I don't use React (I don't think?), so what do I do instead?

Then it says:

"Check you project for existed PostCSS config: postcss.config.js in the project root, "postcss" section in package.json or postcss in bundle config.

If you already use PostCSS, add the plugin to plugins list:"

Would postcss.config.js be in my root folder? Am I supposed to create this file?

It then says to do this:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
+   require('postcss-viewport-height-correction'),
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```

I added that to my .js file (Or does it go in the css file?), and am getting an error "module is not defined."

Could someone walk me through this as if I had no idea what I'm doing and have only been using JavaScript and VS Code for a week? Because that's where I'm at.

I'm on Windows if that makes a difference.

Part of the instructions say to do:

npm install --save postcss-viewport-height-correction

I don't know where to enter this command. I've come across similar instructions several times, and looking up "How to do npm install" doesn't produce any results. I've largely been avoiding using frameworks and extensions and plugins with JavaScript because I can never figure out how to use them, and every guide I can find assumes I already know what it all means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a long winded answer, but I'll try to respond to everything.

PostCSS is a JS-based tool for transforming styles with JS plugins. Typically, you use it as a plugin into your front-end build tool such as Webpack, Rollup, etc. You can also use it as a CLI app, manually running your build.

> I just do everything in VS Code with no plugins.

Which editor you use is irrelevant. How are you building this content? Is it just plain HTML and CSS files?

> I installed the PostCSS extension in VS Code

That extension is just for getting your editor on the same page as your PostCSS config. For example, you might write some CSS with your PostCSS config that will look like totally invalid CSS to your editor, and it would throw errors at this. That extension ensures it follows the same altered rules as your CSS now does, since you're using a tool that changes the rules.

> Would postcss.config.js be in my root folder? Am I supposed to create this file?

Yes

> I added that to my .js file (Or does it go in the css file?), and am getting an error "module is not defined."

JS, but it's throwing errors because you need to install it

> Part of the instructions say to do:
>
> `npm install --save postcss-viewport-height-correction`
>
> I don't know where to enter this command.

From your terminal. NPM (and Yarn, if you run across it) is a CLI tool for installing Node packages, like PostCSS here.

Here are the instructions for installing Node & NPM: https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it.